# Is @repository is required in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

While creating the login page in frontend the values are passed to backend spring boot using fetch request, in the backend created a pojo class for login and have the controller class ,in the controller call the rest api by adding @request body all the values are passed to rest api class ,is this required repository are not if it requires why.

Answer (score 2):

> The goal of Spring Data repository abstraction is to significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code required to implement data access layers for various persistence stores.

**[Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.6.0/reference/html/#project)** is a useful tool for providing pre-built functionality & other convenient features for querying, altering, & accessing your data from a connected data base or other data storage system.

What you are referring to with `@Repository` is the spring annotation. This is usually a class-level annotation when defining your individual repository classes.

It is only "required" if you intend on using these types of repository classes. While there are other alternative means for querying your data, spring repositories are quite handy.